# Construction of pentagon with all sides and alternative two angles given.

Tags: geometric-construction

All sides of a pentagon ABCDE are given. Angles A & C are given. Can such pentagon be created by straightedge and compass?

Answer (score 1):

you have enough information given to construct the triangles $ \triangle BAE $ and $ \triangle BCD $ (Side Angle Side given)  so you can construct the segments EB and BD,

Then first construct the triangle $ \triangle DBE $ (all sides given)
and then "add" the triangles $ \triangle BAE %$ and $ \triangle BCD $ to them.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

A hint: consider the triangles $EAB$ and $BCD$.

Second hint: The side lengths $|EA|$ and $|AB|$ together with the angle at $A$ allow the construction of the triangle $EAB$; in particular, the length of the diagonal $|BE|$ is determined.

Comment: Can you explain me the whole thing?? I am not getting it.